# Can this combinatoric sum be simplified?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, summation, recurrence-relations

Base cases:

$F(n,k,d) = 0$ if $d=0$ and $n>0$

$F(n,k,d) = 1$ if $n=0$

Expression:

$$F(n,k,d) = \sum_{s=0}^{\min(k,n)}\binom{n}{s}F(n-s,k,d-1)$$

I am trying to compute the value of $F(n,k,10)$ where $n$ is a large positive integer and $k$ is a positive integer (can be small or large). As you can see, the inner loop can possibly take a very long time. Is there any way I can simplify?

Comment: First, I would change variables $c=10-d$ to make the initial conditions more natural. Then, I suggest working out the case $k=0$, $k=1$, $k=2$, ... as far as you can (the cases don't interact with one another) to hopefully spot a pattern. Have you tried generating functions?

Comment: @GregMartin I don't know how to use generating functions. I did try mapping out small cases but I couldn't find a pattern. I'll update the bounds though so they are more natural.

Comment: This is a great excuse to learn a bit about generating functions then!

Comment: Are you sure that generating functions can assist with this?